# Add class to ACF multi select

Tags: php, wordpress, select, multi-select, advanced-custom-fields

I have been struggling for two hours with the following situation and I still didn't find the solution. Hopefully you guys can help me out. It's about the following:

I use ACF to make a selection from a multi select menu. I want to show all of the choices and I want to add a class to the selected values.

Below you will find my code so far. This outputs all of the choices. But I don't know how to check whether the choice has been selected or not.

```
$features = get_field_object('features');
$choices = $features['choices'];
$values = $features['value'];

if ( $features ):

    echo '<ul class="checks">';
        foreach ( $choices as $choice) {
            echo '<li>'. $choice .'</li>';
        }
    echo '</ul>';

endif;
```

Thanks a lot for helping!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the key of the current $choice is as a value in the $values array.

if you var_dump the $features array you will see that $values array contains the keys of the values and the $choices array contains both of them.

**var_dump example:**

```
$features['value'] => Array
        (
            [0] => color1
        )

$features['choices'] => Array
        (
            [color1] => red
            [color2] => yellow
            [color3] => green
        )
```

**Code:**

```
$features = get_field_object('features');
$choices = $features['choices'];
$values = $features['value'];

if ( $features ):

   echo '<ul class="checks">';
   foreach ( $choices as $key => $choice) {
      $class = in_array($key, $values) ? 'class="selected"' : '';
      echo '<li ' . $class . '>'. $choice .'</li>';
   }
   echo '</ul>';

endif;
```